# Filtering TableView with filter parameters inside a VBox JavaFX-8

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8, filtering

Alright, I ditched a GridPane backed table implementation to a proper TableView.

In the table, the left column is an ImageView and the right column is a VBox with labels in it.

The code below is modified to not include any data in my database.

```
public ObservableList<Users> showUserData() {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        Image image = new Image("file:///" + [path to whatever image in your PC]);
        VBox vbox  = new VBox();

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Name: " + "a name"), 
            new Label("Username: " + "a username"), 
            new Label("Position: " + "a position"));

        ImageView pic = new ImageView();
        pic.setFitHeight(150);
        pic.setFitWidth(150);
        pic.setImage(image);
        pic.setSmooth(true);
        pic.setPreserveRatio(true);
        users.add(new Users(pic, vbox));

    }

    return users;
}
```

This is then passed into the initialize method where the actual population of the table takes place.

The Users class looks like this by the way:

```
public class Users {
    private ImageView userImage;
    private VBox userDetails;

    public Users() {
        this.userImage = null;
        this.userDetails = null;
    }

    public Users(ImageView userImage, VBox userDetails) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }

    public ImageView getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(ImageView userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public VBox getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetails(VBox userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }
}
```

The program works as intended, I can see the table with the images and the VBox with details in it.

Now I want to add a TextField that filters the table, with the filter parameters being the text inside the labels.

I get that I need to put an ObservableList in a FilteredList and then in a SortedList.

But since the filter parameters are placed inside a VBox and not in individual columns, any example I see on the internet isn't applicable (unless I'm just that dumb). Plus, the parameters are inside a Label and not just plain Strings.

I've been following this tutorial for filtering: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/.

This is pretty much a special case I think, but design demands that I stick to it. I need help, tips, or just any sort of direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data in the items, not the `Node`s displaying them! You can use `cellFactory`s creating cells that display the data the way you like it to be displayed:

```
public class UserDetails {

    private final String name;
    private final String username;
    private final String position;

    public UserDetails(String name, String username, String position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

}
```

```
public class User {
    private UserDetails userDetails;
    private Image image;

    public User(UserDetails userDetails, Image image) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

}
```

```
public ObservableList<User> showUserData() {
    ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        users.add(new User(
                new UserDetails("a name", "a username", "a position"),
                new Image("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png")));

    }

    return users;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<User> table = new TableView<>(showUserData());

    TableColumn<User, Image> imageColumn = new TableColumn<>();
    TableColumn<User, UserDetails> userDetailsColumn = new TableColumn<>();
    table.getColumns().addAll(imageColumn, userDetailsColumn);

    imageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("image"));
    userDetailsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userDetails"));

    imageColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<User, Image>() {

        private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        {
            imageView.setFitHeight(150);
            imageView.setFitWidth(150);
            imageView.setSmooth(true);
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                imageView.setImage(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                imageView.setImage(item);
                setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        }

    });

    userDetailsColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<User, UserDetails>() {

        private final Label nameLabel = new Label();
        private final Label userNameLabel = new Label();
        private final Label positionLabel = new Label();
        private final VBox vbox = new VBox(nameLabel, userNameLabel, positionLabel);

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(UserDetails item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                nameLabel.setText("Name: "+item.getName());
                userNameLabel.setText("Username: "+item.getUsername());
                positionLabel.setText("Position: "+item.getPosition());
                setGraphic(vbox);
            }
        }

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(table);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This can drastically reduce the footprint, if a large number of users is created, since it does not store the large `Node`s classes for every item, but reuses the ones associated with every cell...

This should allow you to create the predicate depending on the text easily:

```
TextField textField = ...
FilteredList<User> filteredList = ...

textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> filteredList.setPredicate(newValue.isEmpty()
                      ? null
                      : user -> user.getName().contains(newValue)
                                || user.getUsername().contains(newValue)
                                || user.getPosition().contains(newValue)));
```

Comment: It took a little bit of work, but I made it happen, thanks! By the way, you wouldn't know of any way to refresh the table once a row is inserted, do you?

Comment: You mean like using observable properties (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview/7289/propertyvaluefactory#t=201703230612594013393  / http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2229/tableview/7288/sample-tableview-with-2-columns#t=201703230612594013393)? Alternatively starting with javafx 8u60 there is a `refresh` method in `TableView` that should update all cells...